# Facebook C# SDK ver 5 - Samples

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to run the samples but having a couple of problems.
1. the CASPNETWebRegistrationForm - I get an error of "Invalid 'client_id'." when I run app. I've set the app id and key in web.config.

1. I just can't get the CASPNETWebsite to run - I always get a response from Facebook that says "An error occured - please try again later"
   The URL returned from Facebook is https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?api_key={185034998201688}&app_id={185034998201688}&display=popup&fbconnect=1&locale=en_US&method=permissions.request&next=http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php%23cb%3Df9b7e2c4%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A5000%252Ff7f1e1a04%26relation%3Dopener%26transport%3Dpostmessage%26frame%3Df36d8dadac%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&return_session=1&sdk=joey&session_version=3

I notice the api-key and the app-id are the same... but I have correctly setup web.config.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, I'm not having much luck with the samples, though I believe you should leave out the curly braces in the config ie.
        appId = "185034998201688"
        appSecret = "185034998201688"

Have you filled out all the facebook application settings on the facebook webpage. I found i was missing the Canvas URL and a few other URLs, and filling this out made things work a little better.